# Where is gradle tasks in Android Studio 4.1?

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated my android studio to 4.1. But I can't find Gradle tasks in the Gradle tab. Does anybody know where these Gradle tasks moved?

Answer (score 0):

On the Gradle tab if you can see the project name but there isn't any task, right-click on the project name, and then in the opened dialog click on the "Reload Gradle Project".